# how to iterate a list in jsp from the values obtained from mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

i have written a program to select a particular column from mysql database in java and i want to display it on my server side using jsp.
In my jsp page , i have a select tag and some options which when selected will display the values of that options from my database

eg : airport will display the values of only airport which i have inserted in my database
When i debug my code on server, i can see the values like this [abc , xyz] but when i run it on server i can see only see the option(airport) which i selected as my output instead of the values.

So i guess i need to iterate the list , i did some research on how to iterate the list in jsp page 2 , but i guess its not the way how i should use it

code for the above :

java side , java code to select the column from database (working fine)

```
    public List readCategoryMsg(String gcm_msg_type) {
    List msgList = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = (Connection)  
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gcm", 
        "root", "root");
        state = (Statement) connection.createStatement();

        prep = (PreparedStatement) connection
                .prepareStatement("Select gcm_message from gcm_msg where 
        gcm_msg_type = ?");
        prep.setString(1, gcm_msg_type);
        rSet = prep.executeQuery();
        while (rSet.next()) {
            String msg_type = rSet.getString("gcm_message");
            msgList.add(msg_type);

        }

        connection.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return msgList;
    }
```

jsp page 1: (which has options to select and submit it to the action page to display the output)

```
        <form action="category_type_results.jsp" method="get">
        <div align="left">
            <br><select name="category_type">
                <option value="airport">Airport</option>
                <option value="art gallery">Art Gallery</option>
                <option value="atm">ATM</option>
                <option value="bank">Bank</option>
                <option value="book store">Book Store</option>
                <option value="bus station">Bus Station</option>
                <option value="cafe">Cafe</option>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Show Category Message " />
          </div>
  </form>
```

jsp page 2 : category_type_results.jsp

I have commented out the things i tried but not proper , need some help on how to show the list of values of a selected option from my database

```
<%
ServiceSql serviceSql = new ServiceSql();
String gcm_msg_type = request.getParameter("category_type");
serviceSql.readCategoryMsg(gcm_msg_type);
//List<String> msgList = serviceSql.readCategoryMsg("gcm_msg_type");
//for (int i = 0; i < msgList.size(); i++) {
//  msgList.get(i);
}
%>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>

<h3>
    <%=gcm_type_msg%>
    //<%=msgList%>

</h3>

</body>
```

how my database column looks , the same list i want to display on my server side

```
gcm_message(column name)
hello gcm (values)
hello gcm ..
hello gcm  ..
hello gcm ..
hello gcm ..
hello gcm  (values)
```

any sugestions would be of great help
Thanking You

Comment: This is a little confusing. What list are you exactly referring to? if you selected "airport" then you should only be getting one value back. You also said "...my code on server, i can see the values like this [abc , xyz] but when i run it on server ...". You used "server" twice. Can you please be more clear?

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) to iterate through your list:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
</head>
<body>
 <%
  ServiceSql serviceSql = new ServiceSql();
  String gcm_msg_type = request.getParameter("category_type");
  List msgList= serviceSql.readCategoryMsg(gcm_msg_type);
  request.setAttribute("msgList", msgList);
  %>
<h3>
  <c:forEach items="${msgList}" var="msg">
     ${msg}        
  </c:forEach>
</h3>
```